# NoClassDefFoundError when running app on real device but not when running on an emulator

Tags: java, android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

When I test my app on an emulator, (Nexus One API 22) it runs smoothly without fail. However, when I test the app on my own personal phone(Samsung Galaxy S5,Android version 5.0), it crashed with a NoClassDefFoundError. This error occurs at a part of the code where I am using an external library from a jar file.(jaudiotagger) Could it be that my own android phone does not have the jdk to support the library?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the problem is : you're not using the same API version on your emulator (API 22) and on your device with android 5 (API 21).

Comment: Hi, I've tried running my app on an API 21 emulator and it works, but still crashes with NoClassDefFoundError on my real android device.What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

android API 22 corresponds with the android 5.1.And you test the app in you phone which is android 5.0.If your code is not wrong,Maybe the cause is what you said.